# Kotlin ArrayList.addFirst() is deprecated?

Tags: java, kotlin

I'm trying to use ArrayList in Kotlin. Here is the code:

```kotlin
var list:List<PlcStoragePiece> = ArrayList()
list.addFirst(head)  // head is a PlcStoragePiece
return list
```

BTW this is Java's ArrayList:

```kotlin
import kotlin.collections.ArrayList
```

but I get compile warnings!

> w: DevStorage.kt: (105, 10): 'addFirst(E!): Unit' is deprecated. This
> member is not fully supported by Kotlin compiler, so it may be absent
> or have different signature in next major version

If I shouldn't use ArrayList in Kotlin, what should I use?

Comment: What version of Kotlin are you using?
I checked that piece of code on 1.9.20 (Temurin JDK 21) and I have no such ArrayList method implemented.

Comment: `List#addFirst` has been added with [Sequenced Collections](https://openjdk.org/jeps/431) in Java 21 causing some incompatibilities with Kotlin.

Comment: Anyways, you could use `add(0, element)`

Comment: If you want a list you can add and remove elements from then you should be using a [`MutableList`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-mutable-list/) instead of a `List`. To create one, use [`mutableListOf`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/mutable-list-of.html).

Comment: Why are you using addFirst? You have an empty list, you could just add.

Comment: okok I cancel this question. addFirst yes is deprecated. I should use add(). It is IntelliJ idea problem that only addFirst and addLast appear in list. I changed to add and warning disappears.

Comment: The message isn't that `ArrayList` is deprecated, it is that specific method which is deprecated. Also, calling `addFirst` on an `ArrayList` will not perform well (for a list that already has entries), you may want to consider using an `ArrayDeque` instead if you need to add (lots) of items at the head of a list/deque (I'm not sure if Kotlin provides a type for it, but otherwise you can use `java.util.ArrayDeque` directly).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do something like this:

```
var list:List<PlcStoragePiece> = ArrayList()
return listOf(head) + list
```

It looks pretty easy and clean

Comment: Given it's immediately after list creation, calling `add(...)` instead might be sufficient.